# MySql Geometry: How to populate table with a multipolygon from an multi-dimensional array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, polygon, spatial

I've been working on a piece of software that allows a user to add pointers to a map in a way that completes a loop and sets a geographical boundary. Like so:

[image]

This then builds a multidimensional array ready to be stored in MySql as a MULTIPOLYGON.

Each array looks something like this -- albeit a little less stripped down.

```
[
  [
    [68.935,-48.625],
    [69.58,-48.94],
    [70.525,-49.065],
    [70.56,-49.255]
  ]
]
```

or

```
[
  [
    [
      [-77.53466,23.75975],
      [-77.78,23.71],
      [-78.03405,24.28615],
      [-77.53466,23.75975]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [-77.82,26.58],
      [-77.82,26.58]
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      [-77,26.59],
      [-77,26.59]
    ]
  ]
]
```

The multidimensional arrays depth has no limit and is set only by how detailed the users input is and [or] if the area is broken into multiple parts -- think islands.

my current understanding of MySql's Spatial functions is very limited and i'm currently lead to believe that populating a table with a multipolygon requires using a number of linestring arguments, for example:

```
GeomFromText('MultiPolygon(((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0),(1 1,1 2,2 2,2 1,1 1)))')
```

Is there anyway to populate a table with a multipolygon created from a multidimensional array? Something like:

```
 GeomFromText('MultiPolygon(([
                               [
                                 [
                                   [-77.53466,23.75975],
                                   [-77.78,23.71],
                                   [-78.03405,24.28615],
                                   [-77.53466,23.75975]
                                 ]
                               ],
                               [
                                 [
                                   [-77.82,26.58],
                                   [-77.82,26.58]
                                 ]
                               ],
                               [
                                 [
                                   [-77,26.59],
                                   [-77,26.59]
                                 ]
                               ]
                             ]
                           ))')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it.

1. Convert multidemenional array to an array of LINESTRINGS then use MySQL functions or something similar to IMPLODE function to generate the Multipoligon same as in your example.
2. Convert array to JSON and use MySQL 5.7 ST_GeomFromGeoJSON function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html